# What can be preventing Remote Desktop access to remote computer?

Tags: remote-desktop

I am trying to RDP to a client host 192.168.3.20 in my office network from home.
I connect to the office network via a VPN 172.17.0.17 (untangle VPN) and can successfully RDP to the AD Win2k8 R2 server 192.168.3.5, but somehow I can never connect to the client host's RDP service.

Within the RDP session with the AD server, I can RDP to the client host.

The thing is, I used to be able to do this. And the last time I did this was when my RDP client is on Vista and the AD master is Win2k3. Right now, my RDP client is on Win 7 and AD master is Win2k8 R2. I don't know if the system defaults changed or what.

I have already set in group policy to allow RDP and remote adminstration exceptions in the default policy. I also have domain windows firewall turned off in the group policy. Also set allow response to ICMP echo requests but no ping response. What else could be preventing the access?

The client host I am trying to access runs Apache, VisualSVN, MySQL etc all of which cannot be accessed. I am guessing it's to do with ports. But why? Firewall is disabled!

Comment: Firewall our Routing... I'd check routing first since you didn't mention if you can ping the host or not.

Comment: Hi Chris, I forgot to mention no ping response even after allow ICMP response in GPO. But I am not sure where to check routing, can you suggest please? I looked in the Netgear firewall/gateway and in untangle and see nothing suspicious. Untangle is behind the netgear. Once its inside the LAN, i thought netgear should just be doing regular switching. It doesn't make any sense to me that it can route to the server but not the client.

Comment: Compare the routing tables of the XP client and the Win2k3 server. See if there are any differences. Particularly, looking for an entry related to the IP range of VPN clients.

Comment: I will try to do that... but it will be difficult because I do not have these OS already since they have been upgraded!

Comment: Sorry, meant to say the Client and Win2k8 server. Basically the one on the network that works and the one that doesn't; there's got to be something different.

Comment: I used WireShark and see that packets sent through the untangle gateway never got back. So I added a static route in the Netgear to route VPN IPs back to the untangle gateway and it actually worked. Is this considered a dirty hack?

Comment: the netgear router should have a static route for the VPN gateway device anyway...

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a sniffer like [WireShark](http://wireshark.org) and check the whole routing path step by step to see where the packets start disappearing.

Comment: I used WireShark and see that packets sent through the untangle gateway never got back. So I added a static route in the Netgear to route VPN IPs back to the untangle gateway and it actually worked. Is this considered a dirty hack?

Comment: It is. Without seeing your full routing confg, I can't say for sure, but I suspect you VPN IPs aren't normally routable from your workstations. A usual setup in a small network is to make IPs that VPN stations get to be on the same subnet as all other office computers so default routes on the latter always include them.